# GameTime.ElapsedGameTime Not Changing

Tags: c#, xna, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, monogame

I am trying to figure out how to create a Timer in my XNA game. I am using MonoGame and developing for Windows 8 RT. When I check GameTime.ElapsedGameTime using this:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        TimeSpan mean = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime - last;
        Debug.WriteLine(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.ToString());
        ...
```

ElapsedGameTime is always 00:00:00.0166666. It does not change from this value. Why is this so?

Comment: where is last being updated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ElapsedGameTime` measures the time since the last update (ie, last frame has been drawn). What you probably want is `TotalGameTime`, which will give you the total time the game has been running.

Comment: Thanks, should have looked in to the documentation more

Comment: No worries, I did exactly the same thing when I made my first timer in XNA :)

Comment: +1 This has confused me as well. However, no matter what you say: **There...are...four...lights!**